# Wildfly 9 datasource spring jpa missing dependencies error on openshift

Tags: spring-data, wildfly, postgresql-9.2

I am want to deploy an application with spring jpa using datasource from wildfly9, I think I have all configuration needed but I am getting an error.

What i have is
standalon.xml in subsystem

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDS" 
   jta="true" enabled="${postgresql.enabled}"
   use-java-context="true" 
   pool-name="PostgreSQLDS" 
   use-ccm="true">
             <connection-url>
jdbc:postgresql://${env.OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST}:${env.OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT}/${env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}
             </connection-url>
             <driver>postgresql</driver>
           <security>
                      <user-name>${env.OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_USERNAME}
             </user-name>
             <password>
                ${env.OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PASSWORD}
             </password>
           </security>
           <validation>
             <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
             <background-validation>true</background-validation>
             <background-validation-millis>60000</background-validation-millis>
            </validation>
            <pool>
               <flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>
            </pool>
 </datasource>
 <drivers>
    <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql.jdbc">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
 </drivers>
```

my spring.profile.xml has

```
<beans:bean id="dbDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="jndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDS"/>
</beans:bean>
```

and the error i am getting is

```
[0m[31m08:57:40,995 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "ROOT.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
"jboss.persistenceunit.\"ROOT.war#my-jpa\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.\"\\n            java:comp\".env.jdbc.\"PostgreSQLDS\\n        \"]",
"jboss.persistenceunit.\"ROOT.war#my-jpa\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.\"\\n            java:comp\".env.jdbc.\"PostgreSQLDS\\n        \"]"
```

]}

I am not sure what i am doing bad, any help is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this JNDI resource mapping with **java:comp/env** and you need datasource resource reference in your app using jboss-web.xml below.

```
<beans:bean id="dbDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/PostgreSQLDS"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Add jboss-web.xml inside WEB-INF folder with this content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
   <context-root>/myAppRoot</context-root>

   <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/PostgreSQLDS</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <jndi-name>java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDS</jndi-name>
    </resource-ref>

</jboss-web>
```

Comment: Thanks for your respons, but unfortunately :( not works same error

Comment: Its working fine for me with that syntax for mysql datasource, i am using wildfly 9.1 Final version. do you mention jndi naming of datasource in persistence.xml ? are you able to connect the ds outside jboss ?

Comment: Yes I do.<jta-data-source>
            java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDS
        </jta-data-source> in my persistence.xml
 am working with 9.0.1 over openshift

Comment: Do you have any `resource-ref` elements in your web.xml or jboss-web.xml files?

Comment: Anyway I changed xml configuration for Javaconfi and this is working now, thanks to all.